# composer inside other composer project

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a composer project for which I need to create a custom plugin that will also use composer. Both the main project and the plugin use the same dependencies but in different versions. How should I resolve these dependencies between each other? So that the plugin uses a dependency from its composer vendor and not from the vendor of the main project?

I found for example this solution: https://github.com/TypistTech/imposter-plugin but it doesn't seem very elegant to me.

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that your plugin and your other code never run at the same time, the solution you found (or a similar equivalent) is the only option short of changing things so that the versions are identical. To the latter, if your plugin is using a new version could potentially save yourself a headache by downgrading to the same version as the project itself. Less bell-and-whistles, but you are back to composer-parity then.

Comment: "use the same dependencies but in different versions." - what does that mean exactly? Completely different version constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Compare as well with another recent Q&A *[Dependency Conflict between Plugin and Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73333395/367456)* which should add more general clarification.

---

As you normally use Composer to resolve dependencies you could also use it here. However there seems to be a little misconception or at least some lack of clarity in your question:

> So that the plugin uses a dependency from its composer vendor and not from the vendor of the main project?

In a compoer project, there is only one vendor folder, the one of the root project, the one you likely meant by *"main project"*.

This paired with the description of only a *"Project"* and a *"Plugin"* there might be a slight chance that it is either one project which has its dependencies managed by Composer (*"Project"*) of which one dependency is the *"Plugin"*.

Or you have just two independent projects (*"Project"* and *"Plugin"*) that can work independent to each other (normally not the case for *"Plugin"* material).

At the end of the day it is less a question of Composer, but just whether your software projects dependencies can resolve or not in a compatible manner.

As PHP has a global namespace and it is static, if you really have incompatible dependencies across the same software packages, you need to fork these and rename the namespace so that you can have one dependency for your module A and one for module B. So next to your a *"Project"* and a *"Plugin"* you also have projects you manage the dependency packages in, e.g. rewriting Namespaces and then offering to composer via a repository.